# How to delete generated table from div using its id?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I have created one div that is not visible, in that div main table is hidden and I'm cloning that table into another div. that div **id** is `main-div`.

I want to delete the newly generated table from that div using its table id any hint?

```js
var aggTableNum = 0;
$('.addAggregatorCompo').click(function (e) {
  const originTable = document.getElementById('aggregator-table');
   let newTable = originTable.cloneNode(true);
   newTable.id = 'newAggTable' + ++aggTableNum;
   newTable.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((element) => {
    element.value = '';
  });
   $('#main-div').append(newTable);
  //attach();
});

// write delete table using its id
$('.component-base, .generate-div').on(
  'click',
  '.delete-component',
  function (e) {
    console.log(e.delegateTarget.id);
 }
);
```

```css
#aggregator-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 1%" class="addAggregatorCompo">Add Table</button>
<table id="aggregator-table" class="component-base">
        <thead>
          
        <th colspan="6">Aggregator</th>
    
        <tr>
          <th> Column Name </th>
          <th> Function </th>
          <th> Alias </th>
          <th> Order </th>
      
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
      
          <td>
            <input>
            </input>
          </td>
          <td><input>
            </input></td>
          <td>
            <input>
            </input>
          </td>
            <td>
              <input>
              </input>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
        <button style="margin: 1%" onclick="addAgg(this,event)">add Properties</button>
        <!-- <button style="margin: 1%">add Properties</button> -->
        </td>
        <td>
          <button class="delete-component" style="margin: 1%">delete </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      <div class="generate-div" id="main-div"></div>
```

JsFiddle Linke:-> https://jsfiddle.net/shreekantbatale2/1w08ksfa/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegate the click and find closest table

---

```
$('#main-div').on("click", ".delete-component",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // in case it is not a type=button and the table is wrapped in a form
  this.closest("table").remove();
})
```

```js
var aggTableNum = 0;
$('.addAggregatorCompo').click(function(e) {
  const originTable = document.getElementById('aggregator-table');
  let newTable = originTable.cloneNode(true);
  newTable.id = 'newAggTable' + ++aggTableNum;
  newTable.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((element) => {
    element.value = '';
  });
  $('#main-div').append(newTable);
  //attach();
});

$('#main-div').on("click", ".delete-component", function(e) {
  this.closest("table").remove();
})


// write delete table using its id
$('.component-base, .generate-div').on(
  'click',
  '.delete-component',
  function(e) {
    console.log(e.delegateTarget.id);
  }
);
```

```css
#aggregator-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 1%" class="addAggregatorCompo">Add Table</button>
<table id="aggregator-table" class="component-base">
  <thead>

    <th colspan="6">Aggregator</th>

    <tr>
      <th> Column Name </th>
      <th> Function </th>
      <th> Alias </th>
      <th> Order </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input>
        </input>
      </td>
      <td><input>
        </input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input>
        </input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input>
        </input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button style="margin: 1%" onclick="addAgg(this,event)">add Properties</button>
        <!-- <button style="margin: 1%">add Properties</button> -->
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="delete-component" style="margin: 1%">delete </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="generate-div" id="main-div"></div>
```

If you MUST, you can do

```
const id = 'newAggTable' + $('#main-div').find("table").length;
$newTable.prop("id",id);
$newTable.find(".delete-component").data("id",id);
```

and later

```
$('#main-div').on("click", ".delete-component", function(e) {
  $("#"+$(this).data("id")).remove();
})
```

```js
var aggTableNum = 0;
$('.addAggregatorCompo').click(function(e) {
  const $originTable = $('#aggregator-table');
  let $newTable = $originTable.clone(true);
  const id = 'newAggTable' + $('#main-div').find("table").length;
  $newTable.prop("id",id)
  $newTable.find('input').each(element => $(element).val(''));
  $('#main-div').append($newTable);
  $newTable.find(".delete-component").data("id",id)
});

$('#main-div').on("click", ".delete-component", function(e) {
  $("#"+$(this).data("id")).remove();
})


// write delete table using its id
$('.component-base, .generate-div').on(
  'click',
  '.delete-component',
  function(e) {
    console.log(e.delegateTarget.id);
  }
);
```

```css
#aggregator-table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="margin: 1%" class="addAggregatorCompo">Add Table</button>
<table id="aggregator-table" class="component-base">
  <thead>

    <th colspan="6">Aggregator</th>

    <tr>
      <th> Column Name </th>
      <th> Function </th>
      <th> Alias </th>
      <th> Order </th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>

      <td>
        <input>
        </input>
      </td>
      <td><input>
        </input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input>
        </input>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input>
        </input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <button style="margin: 1%" onclick="addAgg(this,event)">add Properties</button>
        <!-- <button style="margin: 1%">add Properties</button> -->
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="delete-component" style="margin: 1%">delete </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="generate-div" id="main-div"></div>
```

Comment: my table id is unique whenever I add a new table then new id assign to it

Comment: @ShreeBatale Certainly. No need to think as long as the delete button is inside the table you want to delete. BUt see my update in a minute

Comment: sure! I want to delete a table using its id.

Comment: why?  this solves your issue.  why specifically do you want to use the id and complicate the issue needlessly? @ShreeBatale

Comment: @Taplar okay!  I just want to know how to delete the table using its table id

Comment: Please see update. I am using ID in the second example - I create the ID from the number of tables in the div instead of adding to a thing

Comment: Nvm, it's using a data id, not an actual id. XD.  Anyways, forcing the usage of an id in this use case still seems like a code smell.

Comment: @Taplar Hence the "If you MUST" ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(this).closest('table.component-base').remove();
```

will remove the parent table with class "component-base".

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shafeekb4u/9jc0mdup/2/)**

Comment: I already suggested that. And why not keep the code here at SO in a snippet?